# Do not enforce lines-around-comment for JSDoc

Tags: javascript, eslint

I would like to apply an ESLint rule that forces newlines before and after `/* block comments */` but not around `/** JSDoc comments */`. For those, I'd like a newline *before the comment only*, but I can't figure out how to set up a rule to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

My goal for valid comments:

```
const a = 1;

/*
 * This multiline comment has
 * newlines above and below it
 */

const b = 2;

/**
 * This javadoc describes the function
 * direction below it and should have
 * a newline above it, but not below
 */
const myFunc = () => {}
```

I've attempted setting up an ignorePatter within the `lines-around-comment` setting but it either applies to both types of block comments, neither, or just crashes ESLint.

This attempt ignores both types of block comments for some reason

```
...

    "lines-around-comment": [
      "warn",
      {
        "afterBlockComment": true,
        "beforeLineComment": true
        "ignorePattern": "\\*\\*"
      }
    ],
...
```

This one applies to neither

```
...
    "lines-around-comment": [
      "warn",
      {
        "afterBlockComment": true,
        "beforeLineComment": true
        "ignorePattern": "\\*"
      }
    ],
...
```

And this one crashes ESLint

```
...
    "lines-around-comment": [
      "warn",
      {
        "afterBlockComment": true,
        "beforeLineComment": true
        "ignorePattern": "*"
      }
    ],
...
```

I'll also add that I am ignoring (via an exception) the requirement for `spaced-comment`s when using JSDoc via this config:

```
...
    "spaced-comment": [
      "error",
      "always",
      { "exceptions": ["*"] }
    ]
...
```

Full ESLint file:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "plugins": [],
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "array-callback-return": "error",
    "no-self-compare": "error",
    "no-template-curly-in-string": "error",
    "curly": [
      "warn",
      "all"
    ],
    "default-case": "error",
    "dot-notation": "warn",
    "eqeqeq": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "no-else-return": "warn",
    "no-var": "error",
    "prefer-const": "error",
    "prefer-template": "error",
    "radix": "error",
    "array-bracket-newline": [
      "error",
      "consistent"
    ],
    "array-bracket-spacing": [
      "warn",
      "always",
      {
        "singleValue": false,
        "objectsInArrays": false,
        "arraysInArrays": false
      }
    ],
    "array-element-newline": [
      "warn",
      {
        "multiline": true,
        "minItems": 3
      }
    ],
    "arrow-parens": [
      "warn",
      "as-needed"
    ],
    "arrow-spacing": [
      "error",
      {
        "before": true,
        "after": true
      }
    ],
    "block-spacing": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "brace-style": [
      "error",
      "1tbs"
    ],
    "comma-dangle": [
      "warn",
      "always-multiline"
    ],
    "comma-spacing": [
      "error",
      {
        "before": false,
        "after": true
      }
    ],
    "dot-location": [
      "error",
      "property"
    ],
    "eol-last": [
      "warn",
      "always"
    ],
    "func-call-spacing": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ],
    "function-call-argument-newline": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ],
    "function-paren-newline": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ],
    "implicit-arrow-linebreak": [
      "error",
      "beside"
    ],
    "indent": [
      "error",
      2,
      {
        "SwitchCase": 1,
        "flatTernaryExpressions": true,
        "offsetTernaryExpressions": true
      }
    ],
    "keyword-spacing": [
      "warn",
      {
        "before": true,
        "after": false
      }
    ],
    "lines-around-comment": [
      "warn",
      {
        "afterBlockComment": true,
        "beforeLineComment": true,
        "ignorePattern": "*"
      }
    ],
    "multiline-ternary": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "newline-per-chained-call": [
      "error"
    ],
    "no-extra-parens": [
      "error",
      "all"
    ],
    "no-multi-spaces": [
      "warn",
      {
        "ignoreEOLComments": true
      }
    ],
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": "warn",
    "no-tabs": "error",
    "no-trailing-spaces": "warn",
    "no-whitespace-before-property": "error",
    "object-curly-newline": [
      "error",
      {
        "multiline": true
      }
    ],
    "object-curly-spacing": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "object-property-newline": "error",
    "operator-linebreak": [
      "error",
      "before"
    ],
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true,
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "rest-spread-spacing": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ],
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "semi-spacing": "error",
    "semi-style": [
      "error",
      "last"
    ],
    "space-before-blocks": [
      "error",
      {
        "functions": "never",
        "keywords": "always",
        "classes": "never"
      }
    ],
    "space-before-function-paren": [
      "error",
      {
        "anonymous": "never",
        "named": "never",
        "asyncArrow": "always"
      }
    ],
    "space-in-parens": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ],
    "spaced-comment": [
      "error",
      "always",
      {
        "exceptions": [
          // Allow lines to start with a second *, which
          // basically allows jsdoc to work.
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "globals": {
    "define": "readonly",
    "log": "readonly",
    "Promise": "readonly"
  }
}
```